# LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE in presto

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive, cloud, presto, trino

New to presto, any pointer how can I use LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE in presto for below table.

I need to filter on names in my presto query

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `id`(
 `id` string,
 `names` map<string,map<string,string>>,
 `tags` map<string,map<string,string>>)
ROW FORMAT SERDE
 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT
 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'
LOCATION
 's3://test'
```

;

sample `names` value :

```
{3081={short=Abbazia 81427 - Milan}, 2057={short=Abbazia 81427 - Milan}, 1033={short=Abbazia 81427 - Milan}, 4105={short=Abbazia 81427 - Milan}, 5129={short=Abbazia 81427 - Milan}}
```

Answer (score -8, accepted):

I am able to run below query to get to the mapped data

```
select
id
,names['1033']['short'] as srt_nm
from id;
```

Answer (score 60):

From the documentation: https://trino.io/docs/current/appendix/from-hive.html

> Trino [formerly PrestoSQL] supports [UNNEST](https://trino.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#unnest) for expanding arrays and maps. Use `UNNEST` instead of `LATERAL VIEW explode()`.

Hive query:

```
SELECT student, score
FROM tests
LATERAL VIEW explode(scores) t AS score;
```

Presto query:

```
SELECT student, score
FROM tests
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(scores) AS t (score);
```

Comment: Works great!  In `CROSS JOIN UNNEST(scores) AS t (score);`, what does the `t` mean?

Comment: @MattFenwick `t` is an alias for the table implicitly created by `CROSS JOIN UNNEST(scores)`. So you can refer to `score` as `t.score` in the `SELECT` statement.